# Can I manually specify a varying smoothness of a spline in mgcv?

Tags: r, spline, gam, mgcv

I am fitting a spline to some data using mgcv in R. I "know" that most of the variation should be in the first half of the range of the independent variable. The other half should very smooth, but is sometimes overfit due to "noise".

Is there any way to control the smoothness in specific parts of the spline? E.g. by penalizing wiggliness harder in part of the spline?

[image]

Comment: There is a penalty for overall "wigglyness". Could you try fitting the model by setting `gamma = 5` in the model call? Then try changing it around? Probably not the most principles move but you can see what happens

Comment: can you post a sample of the data? Its an interesting question